# Is there any Canadian version of dictionary of American regional English (DARE)?

Tags: discussion

I am doing a research closely related to dialectical terms.
I am aware of DARE which is the dictionary of American regional English. It shows the dialectical terms by region.

Is there any Canadian version of the same thing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a language reference question, not a language usage question. And please, please, please use capital letters to languages and nationalities in English.

Comment: @Lambie If you are closing this as a resource request, remember that such questions are _very_ much on topic on _meta_ ELU (that is, it is only a very minor issue of migrating). If you voted to close, please consider changing your reason for closing to 'belongs on another site, specifically meta.ELU'

Comment: @Mitch I dunno, I think ya basic google stuff is a bit much: https://www.thecanadianencyclopedia.ca/en/article/canadian-english

Comment: @Lambie I don't think it is even close to what I am looking for.

Comment: Perhaps not but any such book or text would be available via simple searches, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 5):

The [*Dictionary of Canadianisms on Historical Principles*, 2nd Ed., DCHP-2](http://www.dchp.ca/dchp2/pages/welcome) approximates DARE for Canada. It is not paywalled.

Regional Canadian dictionaries, such as the [*Dictionary of Newfoundland English*](https://www.heritage.nf.ca/dictionary/#3720) online, and the [*Dictionary of Prince Edward Island English*](https://www.worldcat.org/title/dictionary-of-prince-edward-island-english/oclc/992509075/editions?editionsView=true&referer=br) in print and electronic formats, might also prove useful.

For an term illustrating the scope of DCHP-2, see ['parkade'](http://www.dchp.ca/dchp2/Entries/view/parkade). Note especially the associated Internet domain and provincial frequency breakdowns, at bottom.

Comment: +1. What's a "six bol' wager", BTW?

Comment: A folk tune: https://youtu.be/Lqriw9F6pzw

Comment: @TRomano, probably originally a mistransmission (if you can call any variation of a folksong that) of a religious reference. Variously read, even in the later 19th (see no. 6, p. 159 in [*English Country Songs*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=umn.31951p01073461e;view=1up;seq=173)). Another (perhaps more recent) interpretation is that the reference is to Ezekiel 9:2.